# How to find the standard names of chemicals in ChemicalData?

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

When I try to get info on acetic acid with the ChemicalData function there are only `"aceticAcid$l^{1}oxidanylEster"` and `"aceticAcid;dioxouranium"`, no acetic acid. I must be missing something?

Comment: Hi, I generalized the title a bit.  This might keep it from being closed as "easily found" or some such reason.  It's also more likely to be helpful to others with similar problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative way to find the `"StandardName"`:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> and type the common name:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click the check-mark and ask [`ChemicalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html) for the `"StandardName"`, which will return the name identifying the chemical in the database:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can just query `ChemicalData` using the entity:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another alternative, remembering that *Mathematica* likes Capitals:

```
ChemicalData["Acetic*"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You can also ask the `Interpreter`

```
Interpreter["Chemical"]["aceticacid"]["StandardName"]
```

> "AceticAcid"

Or

```
Interpreter["Chemical"]["aceticacid"]["AlternateNames"]
```

> {"acetic acid, glacial", "ethanoic acid", "ethylic acid", "glacial
>   acetic acid", "methanecarboxylic acid", "vinegar acid"}

"StandardName" and "AlternateNames" are just two of the many "Properties" of entity "Chemical". To see all of them:

```
Entity["Chemical"]["Properties"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have to search with "AceticAcid" not "acetic acid".